# How to add data from a DB to jTable in Java Swing when tables contain null values using joins?

Tags: java, mysql, swing

Ok so i have a method that gets data from DB and puts it into a List like this :

```
public List<Sale> getSales() throws SQLException{
    List<Sale> res = new ArrayList<Sale>();
    Statement st = conn.createStatement(); 
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select sale.id,product.name,sale.price,sale.quantity,sale.total,employee.name,buyer_seller.name from sale "
            + "                     join product on sale.product = product.id "
            + "                     join employee on sale.salesman = employee.id "
            + "                     join buyer_seller on sale.buyer = buyer_seller.id;");
    while(rs.next()){
        res.add(new Sale (rs.getInt(1),new Product(-1,rs.getString(2),new Category(-1,"",""),new Manufacturer(-1,"",""),0.0,-1),rs.getDouble(3),rs.getInt(4),rs.getDouble(5),new Employee(-1,rs.getString(6),"","",new JobCategory(-1,"",""),"",""),new BuyerSeller(-1,rs.getString(7),"","","")));
    }  
    return res;
}
```

and then i have a method that fills the jTable with that data :

```
public void fillSales(){
    jLabel1.setText("Podaci se ucitavaju iz baze..."); 
    SwingWorker sw = new SwingWorker() { 
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
            MyShopRepository repo = MyShopRepository.getInstance();
            List<Sale> allSale = repo.getSales();
           return allSale;
        } 
        @Override
        protected void done() {
            super.done();
            try {
                List<Sale> res = (List<Sale>)get();
                DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel(); 
                int redova = dtm.getRowCount();
                for(int i=0;i<redova;i++){
                    dtm.removeRow(0);
                } 
                for(Sale s : res){
                    dtm.addRow(new Object[]{
                        s.id,s.product.name,s.price,s.quantity,s.total,s.salesman.name,s.buyer.name
                    });
                } 
                jLabel1.setVisible(false);
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {  }
        } 
    };
    sw.execute();
}
```

This works just fine, but when I delete some rows from the tables they are set to null and I don't get them shown in the jTable. How can I add them too to the jTable with just an empty cell if its value is null ?

Comment: When i delete a row from DB Table which has a FK to another table i cant see rows in jTable which would have a value null for the column that has a fk on it , i use ON DELETE SET NULL .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the database side, if you are not seeing rows because you are attempting to join across tables with null values, then use a `LEFT JOIN` rather than `JOIN`

On the UI side, a `DefaultTableCellRenderer` will return an empty string for any `null` objects. If you are still seeing `null` in the `JTable`, then most likely this is being returned by your database as a String value of "null". To get around a String value of null, you can extend `DefaultTableCellRenderer` and override the `setValue` method to take "null" String values into account. For example:

```
DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer(){
    @Override
    protected void setValue(Object value) {
        setText((value == null || value.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("null")) ? "" : value.toString());
    } 
};
table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, renderer);
```

Comment: I don`t see anything in the jTable if some columns of that row has a null value in the DB and i do want to have them rows visible and theirs columns just displayed empty..

Comment: I have this : https://postimg.org/image/rj1z6atib/ , column "Radno mesto" is also another table that is conected to this one with FK : https://postimg.org/image/73as5etgt/ , when i delete "sef" from the table "Radno mesto"(second link) i dont get to see anything in first table (first link)

Comment: `i do want to have them rows visible and theirs columns just displayed empty` Use a `left join`